# unable to add System.speech reference in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#

trying to add System.speech reference in studio 2013.. but not able to find speech extension in dialog box.[image]  explain how to add correctly.. running windows 8.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049332/i-cant-find-system-speech , this link maybe help

Comment: It looks like this is a Windows Phone 8.1 project - do you have any reason to believe it's supported in that context?

Comment: oh solution was to add Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis.. thnx everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

You're targeting Windows Phone 8.1. As far as I can tell, `System.Speech` is only supported by the desktop framework (either the full framework from v3.0, or the client profile from v4.0).