# C# how to load assembly with reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

I am trying to load an assembly, `System.Speech`, via reflection, so that I can use the `SpeakAsync` method to read aloud some text.

I wrote this:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("System.Speech.dll");
System.Type type = assembly.GetType("System.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer");
var methodinfo = type.GetMethod("SpeakAsync", new System.Type[] {typeof(string)} );
if (methodinfo == null) throw new System.Exception("No methodinfo.");

object[] speechparameters = new object[1];
speechparameters[0] = GetVerbatim(text); // returns something like "+100"

var o = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type);
methodinfo.Invoke(o, speechparameters);
```

But get the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479074/c-sharp-reflection-load-assembly-and-invoke-a-method-if-it-exists
Maybe this is part of the problem too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6049332/i-cant-find-system-speech

Comment: @Marksl I looked at that first question to get the code I have at the moment, but as you can see above, it is not working, so...

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it is a code dump followed by a null reference exception.  There is no evidence of research on your part.

Comment: @BJMyers for future, how am I meant to evidence that research?

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains bug, you can't work with class if you specified incorrect namespace (neither via reflection nor without it)

You use incorrect namespace here (that's why you received null reference exception ):

```
System.Type type = assembly.GetType("System.Speech.SpeechSynthesizer");//type == null
```

Here is example of correct namespaces:

```
System.Type type = assembly.GetType("System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer");
```

**Update1:**
Another note. `invoke` returns a prompt, and you shouldn't exit the programm while asynchronous method is working (off course, only if you really want to listen speech to the end). I added few lines to your code to wait until speach will be finished:

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("System.Speech.dll");
        var type = assembly.GetType("System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer");
        var methodinfo = type.GetMethod("SpeakAsync", new[] {typeof(string)});
        if (methodinfo == null) throw new Exception("No methodinfo.");

        var speechparameters = new object[1];
        speechparameters[0] = "+100"; // returns something like "+100"

        var o = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        var prompt = (Prompt) methodinfo.Invoke(o, speechparameters);

        while (!prompt.IsCompleted)
        {
            Task.Delay(500).Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

Make sure you have the correct language pack.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows)

**Update 3**
If you use Mono, try to make sure that this feature should works on `Mono`. I gues there are some problems with `Mono` realization.

Comment: I don't think I should need to wait for an asynchronous method to finish, why is it asynchronous if I need to wait for it to finish? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @minseong make sure you assembly is in the same folder as your application (you can also specify full path).

Comment: it is in the same folder

Comment: @minseong check language pack

Comment: I don't know what a language pack is

Comment: @minseong https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows